# RPC timeout while doing multicall on `1inch aggregator` on local forks

Tags: decentralized-exchange, 1inch-dex-aggregator

I may be doing this wrong but I think there is an issue when performing multicall `Spot price aggregator` contract.But when it comes to multicall ganache/hardhat all make `Time out error`.

### Poc:

- Performed multicall on mainnet which works just fine
  [image]
- Mainnet-fork using `anvil`
  [image]
- Single call
  [image]

### My environment

- OS: Linux: Debian
- Framework: brownie & apeworx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement from the devs:
`I don't really have many details form your post except it works on mainnet but on a fork it times out. This would usually happen if your txn is going to fail (insane gas limit requirements?) or some limitation in your hardware to process the txn. Maybe there's more reasons but these are just guesses. I'd have to guess it's something with the transaction failing`