# Can we rely on 1inch Swap API price feeds

Tags: uniswap, python, decentralized-exchange, 1inch-dex-aggregator

It is not clear to me how `1inch` swagger API is getting the prices from different dexes. Can we rely on them? As they are not open-sourced. I tried using the `aggregator` but faced this issue [RPC timeout while doing multicall on `1inch aggregator` on local forks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153913/rpc-timeout-while-doing-multicall-on-1inch-v5-aggregator-on-local-forks). So what will be the best way to get genuine data from `1inch aggregators`?